# Error: The method 'data' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
Error: The method 'data' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'.
                            Map _productMap = productSnap.data.data();
```

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_store/screens/product_page.dart';
import 'package:your_store/services/firebase_services.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';

class SavedTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseServices _firebaseServices = FirebaseServices();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _firebaseServices.usersRef
                .doc(_firebaseServices.getUserId())
                .collection("Saved")
                .get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }

              // Collection Data ready to display
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // Display the data inside a list view
                return ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 108.0,
                    bottom: 12.0,
                  ),
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ProductPage(
                                productId: document.id,
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                        future:
                            _firebaseServices.productRef.doc(document.id).get(),
                        builder: (context, productSnap) {
                          if (productSnap.hasError) {
                            return Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text("${productSnap.error}"),
                              ),
                            );
                          }

                          if (productSnap.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.done) {
                            Map _productMap = productSnap.data.data();

                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 16.0,
                                horizontal: 24.0,
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 90,
                                    height: 90,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        "${_productMap['images'][0]}",
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 16.0,
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "${_productMap['name']}",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 18.0,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: 4.0,
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "\$${_productMap['price']}",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                                    .accentColor,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "Size - ${document['size']}",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16.0,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }

                          return Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }

              // Loading State
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          CustomActionBar(
            title: "Saved",
            hasBackArrow: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What type is `_firebaseServices.productRef`? Can you maybe show how this field is defined in the `FirebaseServices` class?

Comment: Here brother you can download the source code from here:
https://github.com/Bhaskar2510/Final-Sem
there are a few more errors in it if you could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code (taken from your GitHub repo.). I will try list all the problems here with some explanation about each. A common theme are a misunderstanding of using generics so I will recommend you to read about them:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

I will highly recommend you are trying to be as specific as possible with all your types in your code since a lot of the current behavior are making use of `dynamic` which is not really needed. By making the code more statically type safe, you can also get the compiler to find a lot of errors which is otherwise going to be runtime crashes.

The following found problems is not a full list since most of your problems has the same underlying problem as one of these.

### Generic types has been removed

In `firebase_services.dart` you has this:

```dart
  final CollectionReference productRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  final CollectionReference usersRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");
```

This is not correct since you are removing the generic type from `CollectionReference` so it becomes `CollectionReference<dynamic>`. If you read the return type of `.collection` in both cases you will see the returned type is `CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

This is important since this type is used when calling methods on the `CollectionReference` object other places in your program.

So this should be changed to:

```dart
  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> productRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> usersRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");
```

### Missing generic with use of `FutureBuilder`

In `cart_page.dart` you have a line 52 the following:

```dart
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                        future:
                            _firebaseServices.productRef.doc(document.id).get(),
                        builder: (context, productSnap) {
```

If you check the resolved type of `productSnap` you can see Dart thinks this has the type `AsyncSnapshot<Object?>` which is not that specific. If you look at the documentation for `FutureBuilder` it shows you should use this with a generic type which tells what type you expect the `Future` to return:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

So change the definition of `FutureBuilder` to:

```
child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
```

Another example is in the same file at line 20 with:

```dart
          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _firebaseServices.usersRef
                .doc(_firebaseServices.getUserId())
                .collection("Cart")
                .get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Here, you have `QuerySnapshot` but forgets that it also takes generic arguments. So based on the returned value from the `future` segment this should really be:

```dart
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
```

### Missing generic in variable declaration

With our more specific types in the code we come to this error (still in `cart_page.dart`) which gives us an error:

```dart
                          if (productSnap.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.done) {
                            Map _productMap = productSnap.data.data();
```

> A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

The problem here is that by writing `Map` you are actually writing `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` which will remove important type information. I will recommend just using `var` or `final` and let Dart automatically assign the best possible type for the variable:

```dart
final _productMap = productSnap.data.data();
```

### Missing handling of possible `null` value

Let's continue with the exact same line. Now we gets the following error:

> The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

The problem is that the `data` property can be `null` in case of an error has happen. I don't know how you want to handle this so for now, I am just going to ignore the problem and uses `!` to force a runtime null-check to be added:

```dart
final _productMap = productSnap.data!.data();
```

But this is not enough since the output from `data()` can also be `null` which your code are not handling. Again, I don't know how you want to handle empty data so I am just ignoring the problem:

```dart
final _productMap = productSnap.data!.data()!;
```

### Wrong value type when calling `ProductSize` constructor

Inside `product_page.dart` you have at line 114 the following:

```
                  ProductSize(
                    productSize: productSize,
                    onSelected: (size){
                      _selectedProductSize = size;
                    },
                  ),
```

Your `ProductSize` constructor is:

```
  final List? productSize;
  final String? onSelected;
  ProductSize({this.productSize, this.onSelected});
```

So you are trying to assign a method to `onSelected` which takes a `String?` as argument. I don't know what you are trying to do here but the current code does not make any sense.

Comment: It is fine to be new to all of this. But I will recommend you start by learning Dart (start with the language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) and then slowly build your application from the ground and correct all errors and warnings as you are writing the code. As your code is right now, there are really too many different repeatable kind of errors to make an easy explanation without writing a book about it. So learn Dart and learn to write type safe code. What will solve 90% of your problems. Then also read about null safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Hey!! thanks for your help actually I'm a beginner so I don't have that much idea of the things you just told me. I appreciate all the time and effort you've put into solving my errors. Coming to the last one on the product size page through that on selected code I was trying to fetch the value of the size from the product size page. This was told in the 14:00 min of this video. So, if you could just lemme know the right way I'll be blessed. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts9D2312FkY
And in my custom action bar page. Do I need to add <Map<String, dynamic >> to that too?

Comment: Yes!! I'll surely read those once I'll get over with this project as I've to submit it to my college by tomorrow. That's why I'm bothering you, again and again, I'm really sorry for that.

Comment: @Bhaskar2510 You can see your `ProductSize` class is different from the one from the video: https://github.com/akshayejh/a_commerce/blob/master/lib/widgets/product_size.dart . `onSelected` should not be a `String` but instead a `Function(String)` which means a function which takes `String` as argument.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. Thanks. And what should I do for my custom action bar page that's the last error left?

Comment: @Bhaskar2510 If you mean the error with `List _documents = snapshot.data.docs;` then the problem is the same for `StreamBuilder` as for `FutureBuilder` where you need to specify the type like: `child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(`. You are then going to get an error again about a possible `null` value but I have already explained how to fix that. :)

Comment: Oh, I was using child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> instead of QuerySnapshot. Thanks for your help. Can you tell me how can I contact you in the future if I am stuck again somewhere?

Comment: My spare time limited so I prefer to just help people a few places like Stackoverflow. But if you want my direct help with Flutter, you can join one of the chat channels here (I can recommend the one on Discord): https://flutter.dev/community . For Dart specific question you can also use: https://gitter.im/dart-lang/home for chat. But if you have a specific question, I will recommend you writing an example on the problem, explain the expected outcome and then post the problem on Stackoverflow. (Also because I am not really using Flutter so my knowledge is very limited on the subject). :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235054/discussion-between-bhaskar2510-and-julemand101).

Comment: Could you please help me more with this error too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68444061/bad-state-field-does-not-exist-within-the-documentsnapshotplatform-error-caus

Answer (score 0):

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }
```

Convert the snapshot to `AsyncSnapshot` snapshot to solve this error. This works for me.